# heroku its calling javascript code that its not in my project of ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

as the tittle said i have a lot of javascript that its not in the project, i have in the project before but now i dont use them anymore so i stop calling them in the application.js and in my test heroku server it works but in my main server its not! and i dont know why.

```
test server: morning-shelf-6185.herokuapp.com.
run server: www.apptrendit.com.
```

if you compare the 2 application.js the code are a lot different.

```
test server: https://morning-shelf-6185.herokuapp.com/assets/application-5c4208e2bfaa870785d03c0aa2febd5c.js
run server: https://morning-shelf-6185.herokuapp.com/assets/application-5c4208e2bfaa870785d03c0aa2febd5c.js
```

i use heroku for the both of them but 1 of them is a development server and the other is a master server but the 2 of them have the same code and files when i see it with my sublime text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime u make a huge change on your assets do this:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

in local and then just add, commit and push it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably related to the assets pipeline.

You may want to run `RAILS_ENV=production  rake assets:precompile` before deploying to your main server. If you use `capistrano` you can automate the process.

Comment: where exactly i need to do this?

Comment: You can run the rake command in the app directory. An up-to-date assets directory will be created in the public directory. Just deploy it on your server. How did you deploy your app on `run server` in the first place ?

Comment: mmm i just git add, commit and then push but after that i see that all is working on the test server

Comment: `run server` is also an heroku instance ?

Comment: yeah!, i try to do the rake: precompile but it says this: ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
i need to put a key somewhere in here?RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Comment: Well, I just check your files. There are the same. Maybe the problem is simply you didn't clear your browser's cache.

Comment: i figure out but just because u help me thanks you very much!